# Landscaping contractor not removing bin from driveway

Tags: civil-law, private-property

I recently hired a contractor to do my house's landscaping.
For this purpose my contractor rented a bin from a third party and placed it on my driveway ( of course with my permission) .

Now the landscaping work completed 7 days back and but the contractor has not removed the bin from my driveway.

- My contractor is telling me that he has paid the rental company the
  owed amount so they should pick it.
- When I call the rental company
  they say the contractor has not paid the money and hence will not
  pick the bin until I get my money.

Can some one please advise what actions I can take. As I am getting the same reply from both of them repeatedly.

**Few Notes:**

- I have paid contractor in full .
- My correspondence with contractor has been on the text messages.
- I have recently also sent an email to rental company and the contractor asking them to remove the bin by certain date but no action has been taken.

**Location** : Toronto, Ontario, Canada

Comment: Why on Earth did you pay a contractor in full when they clearly hadn’t finished?

Comment: I actually chose not to pay him advance and only pay once the work was "done". I would think that a  bin is an asset for some one and this is the first thing company will collect. Anyways, another life lesson !

Answer (score 2):

A contract exists between you and the landscape-contractor, and you have no contract with the bin-rental company. You are responsible for paying the landscaper, and he is responsible for doing the work. If he has to enter into a contract with someone else to rent equipment, that is his choice and responsibility. Cleaning up is part of the job, and even though you have paid him, he is still obligated to finish the job. In other words, it's not your problem, it's his problem. Unfortunately, you may have to hire a lawyer to sue him for breach of contract. The main point to remember is that it is not *your* responsibility, it's the *contractor's* responsibility, to finish the job.